# ClearCase: Moved file's location in views on Old label

Tags: version-control, clearcase

Lets say I did the following in ClearCase:

1) Applied a label to a view.

2) Moved a file from one directory to another and modified my build related files accordingly.

3) Create a fresh view on the previously created label.

What will be the location of the moved file in the new view? Will it be in the older directory? Or will it be in the new directory? In case it'll be in the new directory, what will happen if the new directory wasn't there at the time of label creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in the **older** directory:

Moving a file involves creating a new version in the:

- source directory (which unreference the file you are moving)
- target directory (which reference the moved file)

Both of those versions are *not* labelled with the "previously created label": they won't be selected by your new view.

Comment: confirmed practically... :)